# How do I set properties via map constructors in an inherited class in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

```
 class A {
     String a
 }

 class B extends A {
     String b
 }
```

Now I want to set both properties via map construction when creating an instance of `B`

```
 def instance = new B(a: "foo", b: "bar")
 assert instance.b != null
```

Only it doesnt work.

Actually it does work in pure Groovy but it doesnt work with Grails domain objects in Spock tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following test passes with Grails 2.3.8.

A super classs...

```
// grails-app/domain/inheritedproperties/SuperClass.groovy
package inheritedproperties

class SuperClass {
    String a
}
```

A subclass...

```
// grails-app/domain/inheritedproperties/SubClass.groovy
package inheritedproperties

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    String b
}
```

A Spock spec...

```
// test/unit/inheritedproperties/SubClassSpec.groovy
package inheritedproperties

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(SubClass)
@Mock(SuperClass)
class SubClassSpec extends Specification {

    void "test binding inherited properties"() {
        when:
        def instance = new SubClass(a: 'A', b: 'B')

        then:
        'A' == instance.a
        'B' == instance.b
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. It seems my problem stemmed from the fact that I was running `test-app`from within a running grails instance and that grails seems to have some serious problems when changing domain object. If I let my tests run via `grails test-app` the problem vanishes